# How to prevent character from going through walls. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity here and I have a capsule for a player and a moving wall. When ever the player touches the wall, it can just go through and walk out the other side, and I kind of don't want that. The screenshot below demonstrates what I mean.

Player in moving wall

[image: 1]

I tried to use rigid body and collisions to help give me a solution, but that didn't stop the problem. I'm now not really sure what the best thing is to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbody should be able to do the trick. You said that it did not work, so here are a few things you need to make sure you have done for the Rigidbody collisions to work properly:

- Give the player a Rigidbody component
- Give the player a collider (best use capsule collider)
- Give the wall a collider (it looks like a box collider would work best)
- When you move the player, move them with the function `Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPos)` or by setting the velocity with `Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(newVelocity)`
- The "Is Kinematic" checkbox of the player's Rigidbody component is un-checked (set to false)

Comment: I have all a rigidbody and a capsule collider on the player and a rigidbody and box collider on the wall, but it's still now working. Everything else you told me to do is also done btw.